# Get name and values of a form post

Tags: php

How can I print the name and values of a submitted form.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
  echo 'Name: '.$key."<br>\n";
  echo 'Value: '.$val."<br><br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
print_r($_REQUEST)
?>
```

Comment: In PHP, $_REQUEST contains the data from $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIES, and the original poster asked for just $_POST.

Comment: Actually your wrong, he asked for parameter in a form, by default parameter are passed in GET. This is why I put $_REQUEST instead of simply $_POST.